# table saw -- install release lever

Tags: table-saw

A question to those who use Mastercraft 10" Table saw, Model 055-6755-8. I just got the used one (but in good shape) from someone, and the riving knife wasn't installed (I do have it though), moreover release lever wasn't installed either (please see attached photo).

I googled, but could not find how to correctly install the lever to the inner side board under the table insert.

Could someone please send a photo of the lever attached in their table saw, so that I know what to do :) Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Mastercraft is Canadian Tire, no? Take the switch and the model number there. If they don't have similar models available in-store, ask someone. I don't buy many tools beyond my auto-mechanic tools from there. That said, the reason I buy my wrenches and gearhead stuff from that store is because they have quite the "lifetime warranty". Second hand, I'm not so sure, but they will likely at minimum provide guidance.

Comment: Yes the tool will make it through the lifetime of one repair!

Comment: Here is a pdf for the saw with instructions for adjustments and setup. You might find what you are looking for in there. https://www.canadiantire.ca/content/dam/canadian-tire/manuals/0556755_EN.pdf